# n_estimators always improves performance in RandomForest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I get the highest score for the lowest value of n_estimators. From what I understand a higher number of trees should always increase performance. Can anyone explain what happens here?

input:

```
# estimate n_estimators

param_test1 = {'n_estimators': range(20, 800, 30)}

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 10,
                         oob_score = True,
                         max_depth = 6, 
                         max_features = 'sqrt')

gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=clf, 
    param_grid=param_test1,
    scoring='roc_auc',
    iid=False,
    cv=5)

gsearch1.fit(X, y)
gsearch1.grid_scores_, gsearch1.best_params_, gsearch1.best_score_
```

output:

```
([mean: 0.87685, std: 0.03149, params: {u'n_estimators': 20},
  mean: 0.87551, std: 0.02979, params: {u'n_estimators': 50},
  mean: 0.87588, std: 0.02970, params: {u'n_estimators': 80},
  mean: 0.87545, std: 0.03043, params: {u'n_estimators': 110},
  mean: 0.87593, std: 0.02979, params: {u'n_estimators': 140},
  mean: 0.87506, std: 0.02913, params: {u'n_estimators': 170},
  mean: 0.87599, std: 0.02890, params: {u'n_estimators': 200},
  mean: 0.87559, std: 0.02875, params: {u'n_estimators': 230},
  mean: 0.87561, std: 0.02890, params: {u'n_estimators': 260},
  mean: 0.87500, std: 0.02867, params: {u'n_estimators': 290},
  mean: 0.87476, std: 0.02848, params: {u'n_estimators': 320},
  mean: 0.87434, std: 0.02800, params: {u'n_estimators': 350},
  mean: 0.87408, std: 0.02823, params: {u'n_estimators': 380},
  mean: 0.87461, std: 0.02789, params: {u'n_estimators': 410},
  mean: 0.87452, std: 0.02764, params: {u'n_estimators': 440},
  mean: 0.87466, std: 0.02775, params: {u'n_estimators': 470},
  mean: 0.87498, std: 0.02805, params: {u'n_estimators': 500},
  mean: 0.87530, std: 0.02797, params: {u'n_estimators': 530},
  mean: 0.87519, std: 0.02760, params: {u'n_estimators': 560},
  mean: 0.87498, std: 0.02789, params: {u'n_estimators': 590},
  mean: 0.87529, std: 0.02784, params: {u'n_estimators': 620},
  mean: 0.87526, std: 0.02792, params: {u'n_estimators': 650},
  mean: 0.87553, std: 0.02807, params: {u'n_estimators': 680},
  mean: 0.87540, std: 0.02794, params: {u'n_estimators': 710},
  mean: 0.87561, std: 0.02786, params: {u'n_estimators': 740},
  mean: 0.87554, std: 0.02814, params: {u'n_estimators': 770}],
 {u'n_estimators': 20},
 0.87684895838888188)
```

Comment: the short answer is no, bigger `n_estimators` does not always lead to a better model. In fact, usually there will be an optimal number of trees and both bigger and smaller amount will be worse.

Comment: As I know, random forest commonly does not retrain with increasing number of estimators. However your algorithm could be very slow with big number of the trees.